# Storing user data in Json file (JAVA)

Tags: json

Everytime I try storing new user data’s information to JsonObject, the previous information gets overwritten.

I heard that problem is due to I’m using same JsonObject reference, but not too sure how to reset and change the reference point.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show us your code, otherwise it's impossible to tell where the problem is.

Comment: You need to get previous object, merge them, and insert the result.